# Fatal exception :MQTTService NoClassDefFoundError: javax.microedition.io.Connector DaleLane's Systeme

Tags: android, noclassdeffounderror, mqtt

I work on android one week ago and I must to use an MQTT's server in my Appy android(like mosquitto); because we going to work with an Delphy MQTT server. The Android's phone is the Galaxy Young in 2.3.6 ... API : 9

For learn how to use it, I testing the Dale Lane's Mosquitto for android but, After one day , i have found how i can do in forum...
Link for Dale Lane 's : http://dalelane.co.uk/blog/?p=1599

And my LogCat:

```
10-01 10:34:50.203  17844-17879/org.mosquitto.android.mqttdemo
W/Settings: Setting android_id has moved from
android.provider.Settings.System to android.provider.Settings.Secure,
returning read-only value.
10-01 10:34:50.250  17844-17879/org.mosquitto.android.mqttdemo
W/dalvikvm: threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception
(group=0x40018578)
10-01 10:34:50.375  17844-17879/org.mosquitto.android.mqttdemo
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: MQTTservice
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.microedition.io.Connector
    at com.ibm.mqtt.midp.MqttMidpSocket.setConnection(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.mqtt.Mqtt.tcpipConnect(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.mqtt.MqttBaseClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.mqtt.MqttBaseClient.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.mqtt.MqttClient.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.mqtt.MqttClient.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.mosquitto.android.powerviewer.MQTTService.connectToBroker(MQTTService.java:651)
    at org.mosquitto.android.powerviewer.MQTTService.handleStart(MQTTService.java:285)
    at org.mosquitto.android.powerviewer.MQTTService$2.run(MQTTService.java:209)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
```

If someone can help me, thank's and sorry for my english ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really must use the IA92 code referenced in Dale's blog post you shouldn't be using the J2ME libraries on Android you want the J2SE version.

The IA92 code is deprecated, you should be using the eclipse paho code found here: http://www.eclipse.org/paho/